# Can I use landscape in the meaning of situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can I use "landscape" instead of situation? For example, "The current American situation is not good because of COVID-19."

Can I replace "situation" with "landscape"? e.g. the current situation of America is not good because of COVID-19.

When I searched [Oxford Learner’s](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/landscape_1) dictionary, it says

> 3. the characteristic features of an area of activity
>
>    - *We can expect changes in the **political landscape**.*
>    - *Their songs altered the landscape of popular music.*

But I feel like this definition only works for some idiomatic phrases such as "industrial landscape" or "political landscape".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metaphorically, "landscape" refers to a more or less permanent state of affairs. While the two examples in the edited OP refer to changes, they are changes that result in a new persistent situation: "changes in the political landscape" and "altered the landscape". The OP question was about "current American situation", a meaning where I don't think "landscape" fits, at least not until it is recognized as a persistent state of affairs.

Comment: The two examples from Oxford Learner's use some form of change.

Comment: Yes, they do. I think I will modify my answer.